# How can i compare two frames of a Wireshark capture?

Tags: usb, wireshark, diff, hid

I made a capture of the USB traffic with USBPcap and Wireshark to debug a HID touchscreen.

Now i have identified the interesting URB_INTERRUPT packets, but how do i compare the **HID Data** of those?

I added an example:

[image: sample Data]

I want to spot the binary differences to guess in which byte the x and y position is encoded, but i haven't found any diff tools for Wireshark. Also the "Copy Bytes ... as Raw Binary" gives me an empty clipboard, so using Sublime or any other text editor does also not work.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing frames is fairly difficult.

I posted some Wireshark information with the difficulties and some Comm View (I use Comm View) that could be a little more hopeful.

[Compare Wireshark frames](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/1451/is-there-a-possibility-to-compare-frames/)

> That actually sounds like a fun little project if it doesn't exist.
> You might be able to use the perl NET::PCAP library to ingest the
> file, then make the necessary comparison at the offset you desire. You
> could render the differences and frame numbers into html. I wish I had
> more time (and PERL knowledge) so I could give you more direction.
> Maybe someone else knows of something already built (or something that
> could be easily adapted).
>
> I don't know all of your specifics, but maybe a dissector could be
> written for the industrial protocol you are analyzing and do away with
> the need to compare.

[Compare frames in Comm View](https://www.tamos.com/htmlhelp/commwifi/errors.htm)

> Damaged frames are not counted in other charts and tables for the
> obvious reason: No part of a frame with the wrong CRC value is
> credible. It may have a completely wrong IP address, data payload,
> etc., although in real life such frames bear a resemblance to the
> original. For the same reason CRC Errors cannot be attributed to a
> particular wireless AP or station, as it's impossible to determine the
> real sender's MAC address.
>
> Nevertheless, the user may want to check the Capture damaged frames
> box in the options, in which case damaged frames will also be shown in
> the packet list. By default, such frames are marked with red and have
> the "CRC" identifier shown in the Errors column of the Packets tab
>
> Not all the wireless adapters are capable of passing damaged frames to
> the application level. Such functionality is guaranteed only for the
> recommended adapters supported by CommView for WiFi.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could it be, that nobody so far was annoyed enough to compare Wireshark frames manually to actually build a tool to do so? Or why is this not a feature in Wireshark?
I don't quite get the second part of your answer: What do CRC Errors have to do with my question?

Comment: Comparing frames require the software vendor to build that facility in and so far it has not been done. The second part was just further indication of difficulty. Errors came up in the search through Comm View as part of why frames might be compared.